# How do you code to solve raise_error in rspec?

Tags: ruby, exception, rspec

I can't seem to find what seems like a very simple google search. I have an rspec in my program of

```
it "fails informatively when there's not enough values stacked away" do
  expect {
    calculator.plus
  }.to raise_error("calculator is empty")
```

my code for the plus method in a RPN Calculator program im writing is:

```
def plus
    if @calculator.length == 0
        raise ArgumentError.new("calculator is empty")
    end
    sum = @calculator[-1] + @calculator[-2]
    2.times {@calculator.pop}
    @calculator.push(sum)
end
```

But it doesn't fix anything. I'm pretty new to programming especially in regard to exceptions so any help is appreciated.

I'm sure its really simple, but I've been stuck on this for over an hour looking everywhere.

This is the error message I get when I run the bundle rspec:

```
F     Failure/Error: expect {
       expected Exception with "calculator is empty", got # with backtrace:
         # ./lib/12_rpn_calculator.rb:22:in `minus'
         # ./spec/12_rpn_calculator_spec.rb:124:in `block (3 levels) in '
         # ./spec/12_rpn_calculator_spec.rb:123:in `block (2 levels) in '
```

Comment: It's unclear here what needs fixing... What are you seeing?

Comment: I put the failure in the original post, it posted all whacky though, i didn't want to mess with how it was pasted from the command prompt.

Comment: I figured it out... sigh so easy..
get rid of the if and just 

raise "calculator is empty" if @calculator.length < = 1

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want your application code to stay the same, you should be able to use any one of these:

```
it "fails informatively when there's not enough values stacked away" do
  expect { calculator.plus }.to raise_error(/calculator is empty/)
  expect { calculator.plus }.to raise_error(ArgumentError, "calculator is empty")
  expect { calculator.plus }.to raise_error(ArgumentError, /calculator is empty/)
end
```

https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/raise-error-matcher

Answer (score -2):

I wrote as below. I had many failure solving this test.

```
def times
  n1=@calculator.pop
  n2=@calculator.pop
  if n1==nil || n2==nil
    raise('calculator is empty')
  else
    @calculator.push(n2.to_f*n1.to_f)
  end
end
```